Как загрузить файлы на сервер во vue с использование primevue FileUpload
У меня есть компонент для редактирования задачи. В нём я добавил загрузку файлов к задаче. Но не могу сообразить даже с помощью документации.
Собственно сам вопрос: как загрузить файл с помощью POST запроса и передать данные в formData.
Старый код:
function addFileOnTask(file, task) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", new Blob([file]), file.name);
    formData.append("taskId", task.id);
    formData.append("fileName", file.name);
    formData.append("docId", task.doc.id);
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) incomingUpd(mArgs);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "/addFile", true);
    xmlHttp.send(formData);
}

Новый код:
<template>
  <div class="flex">
    <FileUpload 
      mode="basic" 
      name="demo[]" 
      :url="`${this.$store.state.main_url}/addFile`" 
      accept="image/*" 
      :multiple="true"
      :maxFileSize="1000000" 
      @upload="onUpload" 
      @before-send="beforeUpload"
      :auto="true" 
      chooseLabel="Загрузить"/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formData: new FormData(),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onUpload(){
      //Что тут нужно,
    },
    beforeUpload(req) {
      //А что нужно тут?
    }
  }
}
<script>

